# How to place a figure next to text in LaTeX?

Tags: graphics

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{Youssef Amr Abd El-Moneim}
\title{\textbf{IYMC qualification round answers}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5, right]{IYMC}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I wanna make the figure (IYMC) exactly next to the title and author text like the following image:
[image]

Thanks anyway

Comment: does the answer suit your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Both `\maketitle` and `figure` try to take up the whole column.  You can put `\maketitle` inside a `minipage`, but not `figure`.  But since there is no caption, you don't need `figure`.

The main question is how to align the two.

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{Youssef Amr Abd El-Moneim}
\title{\textbf{IYMC qualification round answers}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{float}% Friends don't let friends use [H]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\date{}
\begin{document}
  \noindent\begin{minipage}[c]{0.7\textwidth}
    \maketitle
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}}% align centers
  
  Document resumes with new paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\author{Youssef Amr Abd El-Moneim}
\title{\textbf{IYMC qualification round answers}}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\date{}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}\noindent
    \begin{tabular}{C{11cm}L{3.5cm}}
    {\footnotesize\maketitle} & \raisebox{-3\baselineskip}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}} 
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```